# ∀x.(P(x) ∨ Q(x)) ⊢ ∀x.P(x) ∨ ∃x.Q(x): How to prove the validity of this sequent in predicate logic?

Tags: predicate-logic, natural-deduction

How to prove the validity of this sequent in predicate logic?

$\forall x (P(x) \lor Q(x)) ⊢ \forall x P(x) \lor  \exists xQ(x)$:

Comment: Could you include what you've tried, within your post?  Also, you should include the full statement of the problem, and your specific question, in the body of your post.

Comment: I've edited the post; Now you can edit it to include your attempts, and/or demonstrate some effort from you.

Answer (score 4):

Please see the following image.

[image: It was a difficult one! A lot of things to do... :-/]